# wait till the completion of system call in php page

Tags: php, jquery, python, ajax

I am trying to create an `ajax` call from a `jsp` page to the `php` page. I have included a `system call` to run my `python` code in `php`. My `python` program takes some time to execute. The `php` code runs my `python` code when I try it in terminal, but not working when I open it as a `webpage`. The `ajax` code is giving  the control to the `php` page. I think the `webpage` is not waiting for the completion of execution of `python` code. The `DONE` is displayed suudenly.

**PHP**

```
<?php
shell_exec("/fol/abc.py")
?>
```

**AJAX**

```
alert("ok");

$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:8080/jspui/anm.php",
    success:function(data)
{
alert("hai");
}

}).done(function() { //use this
  alert("DONE!");
});
```

Comment: It should wait. If it's returning immediately, it's probably getting an error. Make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the PHP script, and check the response in the Network tab to see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Might just be a missing semi-colon in your php:

```
<?php

    shell_exec("/fol/abc.py");

?>
```